# setting background in uitableview

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uiimageview

Well I am having a tableview and I want to set background.

I tried this:

```
self.mapMain.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"maptest.png"]];
```

and this:

```
NSString *backgroundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"maptest" ofType:@"png"];
UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:backgroundPath];
UIColor *backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:backgroundImage];
self.mapMain.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
[backgroundColor release];
```

but the problem is this: I can see the image but it is like it is repeated in every cell. And if i scroll  after the list, I can see the rest of the image. What I want is the image to be static not repeated in every cell. So image is the height of the iphone screen and each cell height is 80.

I have also tried inserting an UIImageview in my view controller and then 
did `Edit>Arrange>send to Back` but send to back is not clickable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in viewDidLoad

```
[self.tableView setBackgroundView:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"maptest"]]];
```